# My Azure Function in Python v2 doesn't show any signs of running, but it probably is

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a simple function app in Python v2. The plan is to process millions of images, but right I just want to make the scaffolding right, i.e. no image processing, just dummy data. So I have two functions:

- `process` with an HTTP trigger `@app.route`, this inserts 3 random image URLs to the Azure Queue Storage,
- `process_image` with a Queue trigger `@app.queue_trigger`, that processes one image URL from above (currently only logs the event).

I trigger the first one with `curl` request and as expected, I can see the invocation in the Azure portal in the function's invocation section and I can see the items in the Storage Explorer's queue.

But unexpectedly, I do not see any invocations for the second function, even though after a few seconds the items disappear from the `images` queue and end up in the `images-poison` queue. So this means that something did run with the queue items 5 times. I see the following warning in the application insights checking `traces` and `exceptions`:

```
Message has reached MaxDequeueCount of 5. Moving message to queue 'case-images-deduplication-poison'.
```

Can anyone help with what's going on? Here's the [gist of the code](https://gist.github.com/rokcarl/3aa843b66ee645a038d364c2b700bcc6).

Comment: Could it be that messages are sent in plain text, whereas you're queue trigger tries to read base64?
I know this post is quite old, but I wonder if adding this to the host.json could do the trick:
```"extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "messageEncoding": "none"
    }
  }
```
Look at the default value for python here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-python#hostjson-settings

Answer (score 0):

If I was to guess, something else is hitting that storage queue, like your dev machine or another function, can you put logging into the second function? (sorry c# guy so I don't know the code for logging)

Have you checked the individual function metric, in the portal, Function App >> Functions >> Function name >> overview >> Total execution Count and expand to the relevant time period?

[image]

[image]

Do note that it take up to 5 minutes for executions to show but after that you'll see them in the metrics

Comment: The execution time is still 0, even after 15 min. And nothing else is hitting that queue, I've turned off VS Code, there's only one queue trigger. I have logging in the queue function, but no log is seen anywhere.